# Ordenar View Pager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

Estaba trabajando con ViewPager y me surgió un problema.
Tengo 3 layout creados (pantalla1, pantalla principal, pantalla2) que quiero que se muestren de esa manera, que la aplicación se abra mostrando la pantalla principal y que al deslizar hacia la izquierda muestre la pantalla1 y hacia la derecha (de la pantalla principal) muestre la pantalla2.
El problema es que no puedo hacer que queden de esa manera, me queda la pantalla1 primero, a la derecha la pantalla principal y a la derecha la pantalla2.
Como puedo hacer para que quede como quiero?

Este es el código que tengo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager viewPager;

private LinearLayout page1;
private LinearLayout page2;
private LinearLayout page3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MainPageAdapter());
}

class MainPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position)
    {
        View page = null;
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                if (page1 == null)
                {
                    page1 = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.pantalla_tienda, null);
                }
                page = page1;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (page2 == null)
                {
                    page2 = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.pantalla_principal, null);
                }
                page = page2;
                break;
            case 2:
                if (page3 == null)
                {
                    page3 = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.pantalla_jardin, null);
                }
                page = page3;
                break;
        }

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(page, 0);

        return page;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
    {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view)
    {
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Probaste de la siguiente manera?**

```
int item = 1; //La posicion que le corresponde al view que quieres mostrar primero
viewPager.setCurrentItem(item);
```

---

Otra forma de implementar eso es que al contructor del adaptador le pases un ArrayList que contenga los fragments de tus pantallas (*Debes de agregarlos en orden*).

***El ejemplo del adaptador es este:***

```
public class MainFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public MainFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
}
```

***Y el MainActivity seria asi:***

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

fragments.add(new FragmentPantalla1);
fragments.add(new FragmentPantallaPrincipal); //Item en la posicion 1 del array
fragments.add(new FragmentPantalla2);

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
MainFragmentAdapter fragmentAdapter = new MainFragmentAdapter(fm, fragments);

viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

---

Espero te sirva la respuesta. Cualquier duda, a las ordenes.